# Reading the text file every time or Get content and store it with dynamic array in C Programming, which is best idea?

Tags: c, arrays, file, memory-management, text

I have the text file with 2000 lines and each line contains up to 256 characters.

I need to detect EOF as I'm reading the file.

Should the code process a line as it is read or should it read the lines into an array and then process the array one element at a time?

Comment: The question is pretty broad but here are three things that I think are important in every coding project: 1. does the code work, 2. is the code beautiful, 3. is the code fast. 1 is obvious. 2 means it's easy to maintain and prove correct. 3 is also obvious. I recommend you go for the extra credit on your assignment and prove to your "professor" that you know how to profile your code. Do it both ways and profile them. Then write up a brief report showing what you learned and what other tests might help you learn more.

Comment: Since you don't say what you plan on doing with the data you've read in, I'm not sure anyone can provide you with a sensible answer.

Comment: Hello @ChrisTurner, I don't have any plan, I don't know even which is easy and works best. That's why I getting here some suggesstion then plan to google it..

Comment: If you need to process the data into another format (say textual numbers to binary) then process each line as it is read and store its extracted data. Don't store the lines if you have no further use for them. Otherwise you complicate things by needing an extra array dimension when you process later.

Comment: If you don't know what you're going to do with the data, why are you trying to read it in? You have to work through the problem you're trying to solve in order - there's no skipping ahead or else you'll end up writing something that doesn't work best and have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data don't change in your file, you should stock the data in an array.

In the other case, you have to read your file each time you need to check a line.

Comment: Thank you @Volgar, my file data would not change.